# Basic SQL Query Request

Tags: sql

SQL: There are 3 columns in the table and they are employee_id, month, and working hour. How do you create a SQL query to return monthly total of working hour for each employee?

Comment: Start [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql/topics)

Comment: Cheating in a job interview, eh?

Comment: I used SQL before, I'm trying to relearn/remember everything I know. I also no longer have a SQL environment to practice

Answer (score 1):

select employee_id
, month
, sum(working_hour) as [monthly total of working hour]

from table_name 
group by employee_id, month

Answer (score -2):

you can use something like below:

```
"select sum(working_hour) from emplyee_table group by employee_id,month"
```